# Angular Date picker with custom validations?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I have an Angular app where I want to embed the calendar so that the user can pick among the dates available.

There are only some dates (like availability) that the user can pick.

I also want to give a visual indication about which dates can be picked.

Any suggestions how this can be implemented?

Comment: Show your work, please. Also, questions for the sole purpose of suggestions are liable to be closed.

Comment: I don't have any work per say to show. I'm evaluating the libraries which can  help me do this.

Comment: Check out datepicker in angular UI. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: I put this here:
http://swoox12.simplesite.com/
 if any1 see it, I hope it help.